# How do I get the hostname from powershell on MacOS?

Tags: macos, powershell, parsing, hostname

In a Powershell script for Windows, I have this line:

```
$etcdBaseUrl = "http://$env:computername.local:4001/v2/keys";
```

When I type in the terminal: `hostname` it returns the computer name like: `User1234.local`

Now I'm trying to run it in Powershell on Mac OS.  I have tried to replace the parameter `$env:computername.local` with `$env:hostname` but I received this error

> "Error: "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."

Comment: Try 'echo $HOSTNAME'

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on linux:

```
"http://"+(get-content env:HOSTNAME)+":4001/v2/keys"
```

Problem is that on Linux the HOSTNAME is not populated correctly so I get this:

```
http://localhost.localdomain:4001/v2/keys
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on macOS Catalina:

```
$(hostname)
```

(It is the PowerShell equivalent of bash syntax `hostname`)

NB: other proposed answers don't work because the environment variable `$HOSTNAME` doesn't exist on macOS : you have to run the command `hostname` instead.

Comment: The issue with this is hostname the command does a reverse IP lookup and can be incorrect. Use this instead: $(scutil --get LocalHostName)

Answer (score 0):

hostname the command wont always resolve correctly as it seems to be a reverse dns lookup response. To get the actual computer name use this on the powershell cmd line:

```
(scutil --get LocalHostName)
```

Can also be used in strings like this:

```
write-host "The Machine Name is: $(scutil --get LocalHostName)"
```